# Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/omeganim/public_html/index.php on line 39

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, conexão

Estou precisando de ajuda para resolver este erro!!!

Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/omeganim/public_html/index.php on line 39

O codigo e este:

```
 $pagCorrente = 1;
 if(isset($_GET['pag'])){
     $pagCorrente = (int)$_GET['pag'];
 }
 $mostrar = 10;


 $pagCorrente = $pagCorrente * $mostrar - $mostrar;



 $sql = "SELECT count(id) as total FROM listas";     
 $ex = $conexao->query($sql);    
 $total = mysqli_fetch_object($ex);  
 $total = $total->total;

 $quantPages = ceil($total / $mostrar);




 $sql = "SELECT * FROM listas ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $pagCorrente,$mostrar";
 $wx = $conexao->query($sql);





 while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($wx)){


 ?>
 <div class="engloba1">
  <div>


    <a href="<?php echo SITE . 'nomes.php?id='.$linha->id; ?>">
    <img src='<?php echo SITE . 'php/upload/' . $linha->imagen;?>' />

    <div class='box'>
     <p>
      <br><?php echo $linha->titulo;?> </br>
      </a>
      <a href="<?php echo SITE . 'nomes.php?id='.$linha->id; ?>">
      <br><?php echo $linha->nome;?> </br>
      <br><?php echo $linha->epi;?> </br>
      </a>
     </p>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <?php } ?>
```

Agradeço desde já!!

Comment: bem vindo rafael, o erro está na linha 39 e vc só postou 4 linhas, publique seu código para que possamos analisar o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geralmente esse erro acontece quando a query executada no banco apresenta algum erro.

Logo após a execução de `$conexao->query` imprima o ultimo erro que aconteceu no banco de dados com `$conexao->error`. Ficando assim:

```
 /* ... ... */
 $sql = "SELECT count(id) as total FROM listas";     
 $ex = $conexao->query($sql);   

 echo $conexao->error;

 $total = mysqli_fetch_object($ex);  
 $total = $total->total;

 $quantPages = ceil($total / $mostrar);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM listas ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $pagCorrente,$mostrar";
 $wx = $conexao->query($sql);

 echo $conexao->error;
 exit; //opcional, para poder visualizar melhor a saida de erro
 while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($wx)){

 /* ... ... */
```

Há um erro na sua consulta sql (pode ser um nome de coluna escrito errado,, etc) não da para adivinhar.

Observei um detalhe importante. A sua variavel `$conexao` é uma instancia da classe mysqli? Ou seja você fez um `$conexao = new mysqli(...)`?
O metodo acima só vai funcionar se estiver sido feito dessa maneira.
Além disso você pode simplesmente chamar fecth_object direto do resultset. Algo assim: `$conexao->fetch_object();`

Comment: No database selected                                                                                                
Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/omeganim/public_html/index.php on line 42

Comment: Suponho que você não colocou o nome do banco ao criar a variavel de conexão. Algo como: `$conexao = new mysqli('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'nome_do_banco');`. Verifique isso.

Comment: eu fiz assim : $host= "197.47.180.159";
$banco= "banco";
$usuario= "root";
$senha= "123";

$conexao= mysqli_connect($host,$usuario, $senha);
$conexao -> select_db($banco);

Comment: fiz do geito que você disse só que a e deu outro erro:Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user 'omeganim_e'@'servidor.linknacional.com.br' to database 'omeganim_anime' in /home/omeganim/public_html/php/conexao.php on line 3

Comment: O usuario omeganim_e não tem permissão para acessar o banco omeganim_anime. Pode ser um problema de senha, mas se você consegue acessar a interface web de administração com essas credenciais não deve ser isso. Ou pode ser que nas configurações do banco não haja permissões de escrita, ou servidor em questão não pode ser acessado remotamente (bloqueado fora da hospedagem, suponho que o servidor mysql em questão esteja online). Para resolver basta colocar os seus scripts dentro da sua hospedagem que deve dar certo.

Comment: Vlw ae pcr consegui resolver era com usuário o erro. Vlw pela ajuda